# fetching problem of header of song files

Tags: java, android

for getting information of song header i see the following sites for reference.

```
1)http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_id3.jsp
```

and i created a project with download files from following site

```
 2)http://java.net/projects/jaudiotagger/sources/svn/show/tags/2.0.2/src/org/jaudiotagger/audio/mp3?rev=969
```

i get error even if build with given jid3lib-0.5.4.jar and no main method please give guide to done the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mp3 files you could use the [Java ID3 Tag Library](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/) to extract information.

Comment: i do not know how to use the jar file and i am not stated to do code. i see the sites
http://java.net/projects/jaudiotagger/sources/svn/show/tags/2.0.2/src/org/jaudiotagger/audio/mp3?rev=969
and 
http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_id3.jsp for read header information. i download files from svn / tags / 2.0.2 / src / org / jaudiotagger / audio / mp3 under http://java.net/projects/jaudiotagger/sources/svn/show/tags/2.0.2/src/org/jaudiotagger/audio/mp3?rev=969 .. there is no main class get error for imprort ' cannot resolved' even if i build the jar given jid3lib-0.5.4.jar. please help me